# PHP Imagick - ImagickException(code: 420): no decode delegate for this image format *.jpg

Tags: php, jpeg, imagick

Yesterday I includes [ondrejs PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) and installed PHP5, 5.6 and 7. Everything is working fine except the imagick functions. The exact exception is:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception ImagickException: "no decode delegate
for this image format `lorem.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544" at 
ImageManager.php line 72
```

So I checked all installations and some stackoverflow questions but nothing seems to work. Some more information.

convert -list configure output

```
DELEGATES     bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jpeg jng jp2 lcms2 lqr lzma openexr pango png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib
```

but phpinfo()

```
ImageMagick supported formats   no value
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This typically happens when you install a version of Imagick that was compiled against a different version of ImageMagick than the one you have installed. You should try to install both of them from the same source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was, that ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick where both as PHP extension enabled. I don't know why, but it seems something during the installation of the custom PPA went wrong or not at least not as expected.

Disabling the GraphicsMagick extension solved the problem and all supported formats where displayed within the php.ini correctly and all ImageMagick functions worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Following this post, I've found [a solution](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=22086). My need was for Perl module, not PHP (same error message).

Download what you need [from here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/), configure and install, by default to `/usr/local`.

Then you can recompile your imageMagick, with correct option, and the compilation process will now find dependencies. (adding the path to the lib on you system is obviously not enough).

Pay attention to the installation path, in `/usr/local` by default (so you need to move probably your PHP compiled libs somewhere else, or change your path).

By the way, you will surely need to call the linker, surely what was wrong in your case:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```